# Mimic C behavior - adding unsigned integers

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET the following code causes an overflow.

```
    Dim t As UInt64
    t = UInt64.MaxValue
    t += 2UL
```

It is my understanding that in C it "wraps". Assuming that is true, is there a way to mimic this in Visual Basic? I need this for an implementation of UInt128 I am trying to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know VB specifically (so you'll have to convert it yourself) but the usual way of doing this is:

```
def add (value,addval):
    if value <= maxvalue - addval:
        return value + addval
    subval = maxvalue - addval + 1
    return value - subval
```

It basically figures out in advance whether there will be overflow and turns an `add(N)` operation into an `sub(maxvalue-N+1)` one.

Both the test and the add/sub are safe within the range `0..maxvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

C# has the [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) keyword that allows a specific scope to suppress overflow checking. In VB.NET there is a [project wide setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f%28VS.71%29.aspx).
Check out [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/51f1d3b2-a4e6-4df0-b6b5-f9e0af50e334).

The project setting applies to the entire assembly. If that is not acceptable in your context you have to either create a separate assembly for unchecked functionality or use an approach like @paxdiablo's.

Comment: I did not want to turn them off for the entire project, but thanks for the reminder.  I implemented @paxdiablo's suggestion.